# Taking one approach over [another/the other]?

Tags: word-difference, phrase-choice

Which sentence is correct?

> To what extent, taking one approach over **the other**, can...

Or

> To what extent, taking one approach over **another**, can...

Comment: Those are both correct, grammatically. They are both natural and idiomatic. Which is right *in context* depends on the context, so we need more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both correct and idiomatic, as the comment by SamBC says.

> To what extent, taking one approach over the other, can...

implies that there is a specific "other approach", presumable mentioned and identified in a previous sentence.

> To what extent, taking one approach over another, can...

this implies choosing one approach out of alternatives, but they may not be specific identified approaches.

More context would help.